# Values of $x_0$ for which the sequence defined by $x_{n+1}=\frac{(n^2+1)x_n^2}{x_n^3+n^2}$ is bounded.

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

This is a problem from the [Simon Marias Mathematics Competition](https://www.simonmarais.org/2023.html) (Paper A) which was conducted on October 14, 2023.

**The statement** (verbatim):

> Let $x_0$, $x_1$, $x_2$, $\ldots$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that for all $n\geq 0$, $$x_{n+1}=\frac{(n^2+1)x_n^2}{x_n^3+n^2}$$ For which values of $x_0$ is this sequence bounded?

---

By numerical computation, I found that the sequence is not only bounded but also convergent for all $x_0\in \mathbb Z^+$.

For $x_0=1$, it's a constant sequence $x_n=1 \ \forall n$ which is convergent and hence, bounded.

For any other integer $k>1$, if $x_0=k$, the sequence is monotone decreasing and converges to $0$ rapidly.

$$ \begin{align}x_0&=k\\   x_1&=\frac{1}{k} \\   x_2&=\frac{2k}{k^3+1}\\  x_3&=\frac{P_{5}(k)}{P_{9}(k)}\\ x_4&=\frac{P_{19}(k)}{P_{27}(k)}\end{align}$$

where $P_i(k)$ is a polynomial in $k$ of degree $i$.

I believe there are other values of $x_0$, besides positive integers, for which the sequence converges. I am not sure how to find them.

Comment: Have you proven the sequence is monotone decreasing, or merely made that observation? FWIW I suspect that the sequence is bounded for $ x_0 \geq \phi$.

Comment: No, I didn't prove it, I concluded this from numerical values... @JohnOmielan posted an answer which establishes this rigorously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that the sequences are monotone decreasing (and I believe they also converge to $0$, but I haven't confirmed this) for all $x_0 = k$ where $k \gt 1$ is an integer. However, your explanation about using polynomials in $k$ is not sufficient by itself since the coefficients depend on $n$ so that needs to be accounted for to ensure the values are actually decreasing.

Instead, here's an alternate approach. We have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
x_{n+1} - x_{n} & = \frac{(n^2 + 1)x_n^2}{x_n^3 + n^2} - x_{n} \\
& = x_{n}\left(\frac{(n^2 + 1)x_n}{x_n^3 + n^2} - \frac{x_n^3 + n^2}{x_n^3 + n^2}\right) \\
& = \frac{x_n(n^2x_n + x_n - x_n^3 - n^2)}{x_n^3 + n^2} \\
& = \frac{x_n(n^2(x_n - 1) - (x_n^3 - x_n))}{x_n^3 + n^2} \\
& = \frac{x_n(n^2(x_n - 1) - x_n(x_n - 1)(x_n + 1))}{x_n^3 + n^2} \\
& = \frac{x_n(x_n - 1)(n^2 - x_n(x_n + 1))}{x_n^3 + n^2}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

As you've already stated, with $x_0 = k$ then

$$x_2 = \frac{2k}{k^3 + 1} = f(k) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Next, consider

$$1 - f(k) = \frac{k^3 - 2k + 1}{k^3 + 1} = \frac{(k - 1)\left(k - \frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\left(k - \frac{-1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)}{k^3 + 1} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Since $0 \lt \frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2} \lt 1$, and for $k \gt 0$ we have $k - \frac{-\sqrt{5} - 1}{2} \gt 0$, then

$$f(k) \gt 1, \;\; \frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2} \lt k \lt 1 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Note for $k \le \frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2}$ or $k \ge 1$, we have $x_2 = f(k) \le 1$. Using \eqref{eq1A}, for $n \ge 2$ and $x_n \le 1$, then $x_n - 1 \le 0$ and $n^2 - x_n(x_n + 1) \gt 0$ means that $x_{n+1} - x_{n} \le 0$. This shows the $x_{n}$ values are non-increasing and, thus, are bounded.

We next have

$$f'(k) = \frac{2(k^3 + 1) - 2k(3k^2)}{(k^3 + 1)^2} = \frac{- 4k^3 + 2}{k^3 + 1} \;\;\to\;\; f'\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}\right) = 0 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Since $f'(k) \gt 0$ with $k \lt \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$ and $f'(k) \lt 0$ with $k \gt \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$, then

$$f\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}\right) = \frac{\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{2}}}{\frac{1}{2} + 1} = \frac{4}{3\sqrt[3]{2}} \approx 1.058 \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

is a maximum. For $n \ge 2$, with $x_{n} = 1 + \alpha_n$ for some $\alpha_n \gt 0$ and some $m_n \gt 0$, with

$$x_{n + 1} - x_{n} = m_n\alpha_n \;\;\to\;\; \alpha_{n + 1} - \alpha_n = m_n\alpha_n \;\;\to\;\; \alpha_{n + 1} = (1 + m_n)\alpha_{n} \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

we then also have from \eqref{eq1A} that

$$\frac{x_n(\alpha_n)(n^2 - x_n(x_n + 1))}{x_n^3 + n^2} = m_n\alpha_n \;\;\to\;\;
x_n\left(\frac{n^2 - x_n(x_n + 1)}{n^2 + x_n^3}\right) = m_n
\tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

For $n = 2$, we get $m_2 \lt 1.059\left(\frac{4 - 1(2)}{4 + 1}\right) = 0.4236$. Thus, using \eqref{eq6A} and \eqref{eq7A}, we have $\alpha_3 \lt 1.4236\alpha_2 \lt 1.4236\times 0.059 \lt 0.084 \lt \sqrt{3}$. Consider any $n \ge 3$ where $\alpha_n \le \sqrt{n}$. From \eqref{eq8A}, we get

$$m_n \gt \frac{n^2 - \sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n} + 1)}{n^2 + n^{\frac{3}{2}}} = \frac{n^2 - n - \sqrt{n}}{n^2 + n^{\frac{3}{2}}} \gt \frac{n^2 - 2n}{n^2 + n^{\frac{3}{2}}} \ge \frac{1}{3 + \sqrt{3}} = r \tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

Using \eqref{eq7A}, we therefore have $x_4 = 1 + (1 + m_3)\alpha_3 \gt 1 + (1 + r)\alpha_3$. Similarly, since $\alpha_4 \le 2$, then $x_5 = 1 + (1 + m_4)\alpha_4 \gt 1 + (1 + r)\left((1 + r)\alpha_3\right) = 1 + (1 + r)^2\alpha_3$. Continuing to the maximum consecutive $n$ where $\alpha_n \le \sqrt{n}$ results in

$$x_{n+1} \gt 1 + (1 + r)^{n-2}\alpha_3 \tag{10}\label{eq10A}$$

Since exponentials increase faster than square roots, this maximum will eventually occur. After this largest $n$, the values of $x_n$ will generally still continue increasing, although when $x_n$ becomes close to or more than $n$, as shown in \eqref{eq1A}, they may decrease somewhat instead. However, the main issue is that if we still have $x_n \gt 1 + \sqrt{n}$ for those values, then this continues to increase without bound. Although I don't think it should ever happen, if the value even decreases to where $x_n \le 1 + \sqrt{n}$ (but we'll still have $x_n \gt 1$, with the proof of this left as an exercise), then we can continue with the same procedure as before using \eqref{eq9A} to show that the $x_n$ values will still continue increasing without bound.

This demonstrates that the set of values of $x_0 = k$ which are unbounded are those given in \eqref{eq4A}. Thus, the initial values resulting in the sequence being bounded are only where

$$x_0 \le \frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2} \;\; \lor \;\; x_0 \ge 1 \tag{11}\label{eq11A}$$

Comment: Very detailed analysis, pleasure to read! Initially, I was lost at $\alpha_3<1.4236\alpha$, but then I re-read taking notes simultaneously, to realize that it works because $\alpha_{n+1}=\alpha_n(m_n+1)$. $\quad$ :) $\quad$ Regarding the exercise, it can be established with $(1)$.